# GAE Java- Null pointer exception when trying to retrieve an object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am new to GAE development.
for me insertion using jpa to the datastore is working fine, but retrieval is not happening.

Below is a method which authenticates the user when he try to login.

```
public boolean loginUser(User user) {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("SOAApp");
    EntityManager mgr = emf.createEntityManager();
    boolean login=false;
    Query query=mgr.createQuery("select u from User u where u.userName=:uid and u.password=:pwd");

    query.setParameter("uid", user.getUserName());
    query.setParameter("pwd",user.getPassword());
    query.setMaxResults(1);

    try {
        user=(User) query.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println("user : "+user.getName());
        if(user!=null)  {
            System.out.println("logged in...");
            login=true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return login;
}
```

but I am getting the following errors when trying to execute the method by passing a user object with valid username and password.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.fetchIntField(QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.java:70)
at org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityUtils.getApplicationIdentityForResultSetRow(IdentityUtils.java:93)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1009)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:228)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:225)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:121)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.size(LazyResult.java:115)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.size(StreamingQueryResult.java:151)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1808)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getSingleResult(JPAQuery.java:231)
at com.soa.managers.UserManager.loginUser(UserManager.java:63)
at com.soa.servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:48)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Nov 03, 2012 3:25:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet

> line number-63
>   [at com.soa.managers.UserManager.loginUser(UserManager.java:63)]
>   is "user=(User) query.getSingleResult();"

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Still searching?

I had the same problem and my entity User had a primaryKey named userId that was of type 'int'. Now I changed it to 'Long' and all of my problems and warnings are all gone! Maybe this helps you out!

I look forward hearing from you!

Regards,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

The reason why u get nullpointerexception is that getSingleResult method returns null. Because u used (User)query.getSingleResult(), the typecasting of null value throws exception.

I think there is no related user in datastore, so you are getting exception.

Comment: User exists in the database.
I am able to make him log in, by directly passing the primary key like-
user=mgr.find(User.class, user.getId());
(I have hardcoded (pre-setted) the value for id for the user object.

Comment: Please change query with this query, Query query=mgr.createQuery("select u from User u"); query.getResultList();

Comment: I have already tried the same, but I am getting the same error :(
Pls help me... Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: I could not understand why you getting this exception. Sorry man.

Comment: My project's business logic is almost over, this is the only place where I am stuck at... The same code was working perfectly when I tried with a normal core java project(not google web application project) which used local mysql(not google cloud sql)...
I am not able to understand what is happening, somebody pls help me :(
Thanks @mucayufa for your time...

Comment: password type? its a string only 'eljo' (without quotes).
But i dont think its an issue with password, coz I am able to insert and retrive using mgr.find() method, with same connection

Comment: Problem may be that you do not use datastore index

Comment: how to use datastore index?
When i opened the datastore, it is showing id=0 for all, and it shows a new field named 'ID/Name', which is not at all a field in my entity. but this filed is having valid id values like 1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datastore-indexes  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="HABERLER" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="__key__" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

HABERLER is table name. Write your table name instead of HABERLER. Then create a datastore-indexes.xml file in WEB-INF directory. Then copy above code into this file.

Comment: I am getting same error for the user that exists in the table.
but for the entities that dest exists, it throws -
`code`javax.persistence.NoResultException: No results for query: SELECT FROM User u WHERE u.userName=?1 and u.password=?2


excepton

Comment: how I can create an index which automatically creates ids like auto_increment in mysql...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you that the keys for your entities are of valid types as detailed here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys

The exception you are getting is most likely related to a key issue.